# Numericupdown и streamreader

Tags: c#

Как считать значение numericupdown из файла?

```
numupdown.Value = sr.ReadLine();
```

Пишет о неявном преобразовании string в decimal, все что мог придумать перепробовал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [decimal.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.decimal.parse.aspx)

Comment: Вроде пробовал не канало. Сейчас работает, спасибо